# The proper way to create a Retrofit service in Android?

Tags: kotlin, singleton, retrofit, lazy-initialization

In [this Android CodeLab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-internet-data#3), they created a Retrofit service like this:

```
object MarsApi {
    val retrofitService : MarsApiService by lazy { 
       retrofit.create(MarsApiService::class.java) }
}
```

Here, MarsApi is a Singleton, and as far as I know, in Kotlin Singletons are lazily initialized by definition.

So why do we need to use "by lazy" here? It seems to me that the lazy initialization concept is applied 2 times in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to think about it.

```kotlin
object MarsApi1 {
    var count = 0
    val str: String
    get(){
        count++
        return "$count"
    }
}

fun main() {
  println(MarsApi1.str)
  println(MarsApi1.str)
}
```

As you can see here, even though MarsApi1 is singleton and initialized lazily the `val` or `var` properties are not. And on top of that, you can change the way these properties behave.

Now, on the other hand you will not be able to do this:

```kotlin
object MarsApi2 {
    var count = 0
    val str : String by lazy {
        "saiful103a" }
        get(){
            count++
            return "$count"
        }
}

fun main() {
  println(MarsApi2.str)
  println(MarsApi2.str)
}
```

With this, you will get, `Delegated property cannot have accessors with non-default implementations` error. Whatever implementation you want to provide, you have to put them inside the `lazy` block.

Finally:

```kotlin
object MarsApi2 {
    var count = 0
    val str : String by lazy {
        count++;"$count" }
}

fun main() {
  println(MarsApi2.str)
  println(MarsApi2.str)
}
```

For this, you will get the same value every time you access `MarsApi2.str`.